# When I want to save a data as csv I get an error

Tags: r, rtweet

Currently i am working with twite data for what i am using the rtweet package. However when i want to save my data i got a poblem with it.

I use the following code to get my data:

```
Data1 <- get_timeline("Account1", n = 3200)

Data2 <- get_timeline("Account2", n = 3200)

Data3 <- get_timeline("Account2", n = 3200)

timelines <- dplyr::bind_rows(Data1, Data2, Data3)

write_csv(timelines, path = paste("./Data/Account_tweets_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep=""))
```

The error I recieve is as following:

> Error in stream_delim_(df, path, ..., bom = bom, quote_escape =
>   quote_escape) :    Don't know how to handle vector of type list.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have a `list` column in your data, and `write_csv` doesn't handle list columns. CSVs are flat, and embedded lists are not. As for options to proceed, either

- flatten your data structure with, e.g., `tidyr::unnest()` before writing to CSV
- or write to a different data structure. If you only need R to read them, I'd suggest `base::saveRDS`. If you need them to be portable, perhaps `jsonlite::writeJSON`.

Googling your error leads directly to [this closed issue on the readr repository](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/871). In [this linked discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/303)  it sounds like there are not plans to enable list columns for CSV, as it's not generally clear how they should be handled.

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific function in the rTweet package `write_as_csv` :
https://rdrr.io/cran/rtweet/man/write_as_csv.html

```
rtweet::write_as_csv(timelines, file_name = paste("./Data/Account_tweets_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep=""))
```

EDIT - my bad, I was too quick. It is `file_name` and not `path` that you should use

Comment: I tried it but then it says:

Comment: Error in rtweet::write_as_csv(timelines, path = paste("./Daten2/Account_tweets_",  : 
  unused argument (path = paste("./Daten2/Account_tweets_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = ""))